# Does Canonical provide paid support for individuals?

Tags: support

Does Canonical provide paid support for individuals or is it only for multiple desktop/severer businesses? If not for individuals, is paid support available anywhere?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Canonical does offer paid support to individuals. It is known as [Ubuntu Advantage Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/management/ubuntu-advantage). You can also buy support for server installations and cloud installations.

**Edit:** It looks like Ubuntu Advantage Desktop requires a minimum order of 50 desktops now.

Comment: Please elaborate --- on the linked page it is not evident where support for individual installation is. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that those links are now redirecting to a more generic page. It looks like they only sell support to organisations now, starting from 5 users, based on [this link](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=667)

Comment: So it seems that the real answer here is No... Could be a nice opportunity for a third-part business!

Answer (score 3):

I used Flimm's link and clicked on contact us about our services: http://www.canonical.com/services/contact-us

Although it says for businesses, if you open the job role drop down you can select individual, home user, or even Ubuntu enthusiast. Also under the industry drop-down there is an option for Not Applicable (self).

This suggests to me that paid support is offered for individual home users. I filled out the form to contact Canonical and they said they would get back within 2 business days. I will update my answer when I hear from them. I will pay for support if they offer it and update my answer further to let you know how the support is, once I am all set up.

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: It seems to have changed now. There's no "Job role" dropdown anymore, and the "Company name" field is mandatory.